# Script to compare dates

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to compare an elastic search date with a format `YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` as to compare the results of the past 30 days. So if the given date is equal to NOW()-30D it should give me the result wanted.
I have tried comparing it this way with a script but it doesn't work :

`getMillis(doc["date"].value) >= (new Date().getTime() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  ? 1 : 0`

Another test not working :

```
$total= new \Elastica\Aggregation\Sum('total');
$total->setScript('doc["date"].value >= (new Date().getTime() - 30) ? 1 : 0');
```

This should do this : If `doc["date"].value` is higher or equal to the last 30 days it should give me 1, else it would give me 2.

How can I achieve that? Knowing that I'm using groovy scripting.

Comment: Where in your query do you need this?

Comment: @Val in the `setScript()` in Elastica or just the script part in elasticsearch, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script you're looking for looks like this:

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['date'].date.millis), Instant.ofEpochMilli(new Date().getTime())) > 30 ? 0 : 1
```

We compute the number of days between the `date` field and now. If the number of days is bigger than 30, we return 0, otherwise we return 1.

Answer (score 0):

You achieve same using [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates) or date range aggregation, I suggest not to use the script with elastic search unless and until it is difficult to get the result using search query

Comment: The range query is to filter all of the results, and thus not what I'm looking for. As explained in my question, I'm looking to go over each data and compare it's date if it matches the last 30 days then I would like to increment the variable by 1.